# How to determine line/column numbers from boost::spirit::lex tokens?

Tags: c++, boost, lex, boost-spirit

In its answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715829/how-to-use-boostspiritlex-to-lex-a-file-without-reading-the-whole-file-into/4719117), hkaiser said he would write an example of a token type which carries code position information. I really cannot find anything about this.

Can anyone point me to such an example ?

Answer (score 3):

He was probably referring to `position_token`, which did in fact get released, although there's little documentation.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203490/boost-spirit-parser-lex-qi-getting-the-undocumented-on-success-mechanism-to) has good coverage of its usage.

Comment: OK thanks. Do you know if there is an example or a tutorial for how to use it somewhere ?

Comment: Hartmut gives further details in his answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964228/boost-spirit-lex-qi-error-reporting

Comment: Within the Boost sources you can find it at libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/conjure3/lexer.hpp

Comment: This source code is quite complex! I cannot figure out what information is stored into the tokens, and how you read it...

Comment: `position_token` has methods `begin()` and `end()` which return iterators to the start and end of the underlying input that they matched.  You could use this, for example, to determine the byte offset, within a file, of the matched input.

Comment: I don't see any sign that it tracks line and column information, though.

Comment: @JeffTrull for that I think you'll need to use the [`line_pos_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/line_pos_iterator.html).

Comment: @cv_and_he that sounds great.  Care to make it an answer?  I think it's probably what OP is looking for.

Comment: @cv_and_he hm actually I think he needed a lex-compatible iterator. `line_pos_iterator` seems to be for character-based input

Comment: @JeffTrull It is. I think what the OP needs is a combination of both `position_token` and `line_pos_iterator`.